# Path error 5152 when saving Word document using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

Language version: Microsoft Word/Excel version 16.41
Operating system: Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

I am trying to use Excel VBA to save a Word document on my desktop.

Result:

> Run time error 5152. This is not a valid file name. Try one or more of the following:
> -Check the path to make sure it was typed correctly
> -Select a file from the list of files and folders

I am using Microsoft Excel version 2008 and Microsoft Word version 2008. I am using early binding and I have selected Microsoft Excel, Office, and Word 16.0 Object Library. (Does the 16.0 object library seem odd for version 2008?)  (Windows 10 Pro version 2004. Microsoft Office 365 Subscription)

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/z7gUwuOxZAY?t=1856).

Line with error:

```
.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MovieReport.docx"
```

My code :

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateBasicWordReportEarlyBinding()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application

    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    With wdApp

        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add
       
        With .Selection
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .BoldRun
            .Font.Size = 18
            .TypeText "Best Movies Ever"
            .BoldRun
            .Font.Size = 12
            .TypeText vbNewLine
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
            .TypeParagraph
        End With

        Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
        .Selection.Paste            
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MovieReport.docx"
        .ActiveDocument.Close
        .Quit
    End With

   'Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to save it at the root folder first, like: `C:\MovieReport.docx`

Comment: Shouldn't the full extension be `"C:\Users\" & Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MovieReport.docx"`?

Comment: @xwhitelight after attempting that, I received Run-time error '6294' Method 'SaveAs2' of object'_Document' failed

Comment: @dwirony I received the same 5152 error when I tried that using .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MovieReport.docx"

Comment: What about `.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MovieReport.docx"`?

Comment: @dwirony same 5152 error code :/ I like that logic, do you think it is the "\" special characters in the string? I thought it wouldn't be that since it worked for WiseOwlTutorials in the video.

Comment: @CullerWhale Are you on a mac or a PC?

Comment: @dwirony I am on a PC, Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Huh... this is perplexing... It's gotta be an issue related to your computer or version of Word. I'd try changing it to `.doc` instead of `.docx`. If that doesn't work, you might need to add more of the properties outlined for `.SaveAs2` as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2).

Comment: The simplest course of action is to open Word, create a new document and record a macro using File Save As to save it to the desktop. That will then give you the code you need to use in Excel with the full valid path to your desktop folder.

Answer (score 0):

You must use "ActiveDocument.SaveAs", not "ActiveDocument.SaveAs2". You cannot use "ActiveDocument.SaveAs2" method if you use Office 2010 or an older version. Use the following code and I hope your problem will be solved.

```
With wdApp  
   
   'Your codes...

   SaveName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\MovieReport.docx"

   If .Version <= 12 Then
      .ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveName
   Else
      .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 SaveName
   End If
   
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (in any version) is to find the proper syntax for saving to a Mac OS folder:

- open a file
- record a macro
- save the file (choose your folder)
- stop the recording
- edit the macro
- see how Word translated it in   VisualBasic

example with Word 16 (2019)

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _ "/Users/myusername/anyfolder/nameofthefile" & DocNum & ".txt" _ , FileFormat:=wdFormatText, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _ AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _ EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _ :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, Encoding:=65001, InsertLineBreaks:= _ False, AllowSubstitutions:=False, LineEnding:=wdCROnly
```